# How to sort a List on C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've an compile time error message when I try to use the `Sort` method from *LINQ*. What's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

```
public class tt
{
    public string zz;
    public string yy;
}

...   

var tts = new List<tt>();
var sorted = tts.Sort(x => x.yy); // <- Compile Time Error here
```

**Compile Time Error :**

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IComparer' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: `.Sort(....)` is a method from `List<T>`, not a LINQ method.

Comment: Did you mean to use `OrderBy()` instead of `Sort()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options here. If you want to sort *inplace*, i.e. you want `tts` itself being sorted, use `Sort`:

```
   // Here we should explain how to compare two items (a and b)
   tts.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.yy, b.yy));
```

If you want to have *separated* `sorted` list (while initial `tts` being preserved *intact*), put `OrderBy`:

```
   using System.Linq;

   ...

   // Here while given item x we should provide value to sort by (x.yy)
   var sorted = tts.OrderBy(x => x.yy).ToList();
```